# Grafana - how to ssh a linux box and execute a shell script after an alert is triggered

Tags: shell, ssh, alert, webhooks, grafana

Hope you're having a great day,

I'm new in grafana and I would like to know if there is any way to execute an ssh to a linux server to execute a shell script when an alert is triggered instead of send an email.

Regards!

Comment: Any samples about this? Everybody gives the theory.

Answer (score 1):

Grafana provides a [webhook notification channel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/notifications/#webhook) that you can use for triggering actions.

You can roll your own or use open source tools such as [rundeck](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/webhooks/run-job.html#usage), [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook), ... to take action.